# JavaScript Calling Function2 after Function1 has ended

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have already searched for the problem and found something in here about it, but iam not able to use it in my programm, eventually i havent understood it completly.

```
var header = "welcome";
var text = "hello";
var headlength = 0;
var textlength = 0;

function do_header(lightup)
         {
          if (headlength <=header.length)
           {
               if(headlength !==header.length)
                window.document.getElementById('header').innerHTML=header.substr(0, lenghtheader++)+"_";
            else
                window.document.getElementById('header').innerHTML=header.substr (0, lenghtheader++);
            if(lightup)
            window.setTimeout ("do_header(1)", speed);
            else
            window.setTimeout ("do_header(0)", speed);
           }else{
            do_text(); }
         }
function do_text()
     {
       if (textlength <=text.length)
       {
           if(textlength !==text.length)
            window.document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=text.substr (0, lenghttext++)+"_";
        else
            window.document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=text.substr (0, lenghttext++);

        window.setTimeout ("do_text()", speed);

       }
       else 
       {
          .... eventually start 3. function

       }
     }
```

thanks for any help .

Comment: **1.** Your code would be way easier to read with curly braces. **2.** What's your current code doing wrong? **3.** Your `do_header()` function is not closed. You don't show where you call these functions. `speed` is undefined.

Comment: true do_header() must be closed, my code is doing all right. but iam looking do make it easier by using eventually the .done function but iam not sure how to modify it correctly

Comment: May I suggest you that you can define function 1 with rerurn true and you can call it function 2 start?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. using callback

```
function do_header(lightup,callback) {
    //your code

   callback();
}


function do_text(){
  //your code
}

//now call

do_header(lightup,do_text);
```

Comment: Its working fine, but do_text wont wait for do_header to finish, both starting at the same time

Comment: callback() should be just before the end of do_header () function. Can you please confirm?

Comment: yes it is i put it in the last else case after headlength =header.length (when my function is over)